# Font issue when including EPS from Metapost into XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, eps

I've run into strange problems with fonts in figures included in XeLaTeX document. I have figures generated from Metapost sources with rotated math labels. When I include resulting EPS into document its rendering depends upon including another figure before it. Example should clear what I mean.

`problem.tex` is compiled with `xelatex`, both figures with `mpost`.

When I don't include the first picture, the second one is alright. However, when it's included, rotated label (`$\text{odvěsna úhlu }\alpha$`) is displayed with totally inappropriate font. I've no idea if it's a bug or some hidden feature I am not aware of... (In a little bit different setup than presented only alpha is displayed incorrectly as ligature `ff`.)

I'll be grateful for any ideas.

problem.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[czech]{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics{imgA.eps} %this causes problem
\end{figure}

\includegraphics{imgB.eps}

\end{document}
```

imgA.mp:

```
input fks
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fkssugar} % only helping macros
\begin{document}
etex
prologues:=3;
u:=1cm;
beginfig(1);

z0=(0,0);
z1=(0, 2u);
z2=( 3u, 0);

draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;

uhelR(z2,z0,4mm);
draw (thelabel.top(btex $a - \text{odvěsna}$ etex,z0)).rotated 90 .shifted    (.5[z0,z1]);
label.bot(btex $b - \text{odvěsna}$ etex,.5[z0,z2]);
label.urt(btex $c - \text{přepona}$ etex,.5[z1,z2]);

endfig;
verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex
end;
```

imgB.mp:

```
input fks
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fkssugar}
\begin{document}
etex

prologues:=3;
u:=1cm;

beginfig(1);

z0=(0,0);
z1=(0, 2u);
z2=( 3u, 0);


draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
uhel(z1,z2,z0,8mm);

uhelR(z2,z0,4mm);

draw (thelabel.top(btex $a - \text{protilehlá}$ etex,z0+(0,8pt))).rotated 90 .shifted(.5[z0,z1]);

draw (thelabel.top(btex $\text{odvěsna úhlu }\alpha$ etex,z0)).rotated 90 .shifted(.5[z0,z1]);
label.bot(btex $b - \text{přilehlá}$ etex,.5[z0,z2]);
label.bot(btex $\text{odvěsna úhlu } \alpha$ etex,.5[z0,z2]-(0,9pt));
label.urt(btex $c - \text{přepona}$ etex,.5[z1,z2]);
label.ulft(btex $\alpha$ etex,z2-(3mm,0));


endfig;

verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't providing `fks.mp` and `fkssugar.sty`. However I have already encountered similar problems with inclusion of Metapost generated EPS files in XeLaTeX.

The solution is to convert the EPS file to PDF and to include the latter:

```
epstopdf --hires --outfile=imgA.pdf imgA.1
```